# How to stop announcing the time on macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: macos, big-sur

After upgrading to Big Sur, my Mac started announcing the time every hour.

I didn't find a way to disable announcing the time, do I maybe have to run a Terminal command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable this in System Preferences -> Dock & Menu Bar -> Clock

[image]

The setting is stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist`:

```
$ plutil -p com.apple.speech.synthesis.general.prefs.plist
{
  "SpokenUIUseSpeakingHotKeyFlag" => 1
  "TimeAnnouncementPrefs" => {
    "TimeAnnouncementsEnabled" => 1
    "TimeAnnouncementsIntervalIdentifier" => "EveryHourInterval"
    "TimeAnnouncementsPhraseIdentifier" => "ShortTime"
    "TimeAnnouncementsVoiceSettings" => {
      "CustomVolume" => 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

You can use any Plist editor (or `defaults`) to change the setting, it may require a restart (or killing the Dock) though to get activated.

Comment: In English version its 'Dock & Menu Bar', section 'Menu Bar Only' on left pane, 'Clock' and 'Announce the time'

Comment: Thanks. I switched languages for the screenshot now.

Comment: I have unchecked "Announce the time" and this stupid machine is still announcing it.